# thunderbird - number of underad messages, from .sqlite base

Tags: sqlite, thunderbird, awesome-wm

I want to make a small plugin for [awesome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_%28window_manager%29) WM that will show a number of unread messages pending in Thunderbird. I want to fetch the number of messages accessing directly Thunderbird *sqlite* base. The question is: which base, table and fields should I query?

There are at least 15 bases under `~/.thunderbird/profile/`, including `./global-messages-db.sqlite`. In this base I tried `messageAttributes` table, but with no big success. I could not find development documentation describing the attributes...

Any help here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find what you need in the `global-messages-db.sqlite` file. If you watch the `messages` table, you will find a column `jsonAttributes`. In there you will find a JSON array, from attribute ids and their value. The key 58 is the read-status of a message. So if you find something like `{"58": false}` in this column the message is still unread. But this database won't be updated immediately when a new message is received. (It might even be updated only, when you close Thunderbird -- I am not sure about that.)

So as you see finding unread messages that way will be a bit of the hard way to go. I would recommend you to better create a plugin, that is directly checking the server via IMAP or POP3.

For IMAP servers there already exist an awesome-plugin inside the [Delightful Extensions](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Delightful). I don't know of any POP3 plugin, and as it seems POP3 libs for lua are also rare to find.

Comment: re: `58`: `select * from attributeDefinitions`